# equivalent of $q.when in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable, deferred

I am used to using `$q` with angular 1. I am migrating to angular 2.

Is there an equivalent that provide a `.when()` method ?

for example I need to migrate this:

```
.service('updateProDB', [
            '$rootScope',
            'connectionStatus',
            '$q',
            'storageService',
            'sendToServer',
            '$ionicPopup',
            function ($rootScope, connectionStatus, $q, storageService, sendToServer, $ionicPopup) {
                'use strict';

                var dbReadyDeferred = $q.defer(),
                prodata = [],
                prodataFieldNames = [];

            this.get = function () {
                var debugOptionUseLocalDB = 0,
                    prodata = [],
                    serverAttempts = 0;

                if (debugOptionUseLocalDB) {
                    return fallbackToLocalDBfileOrLocalStorageDB();
                }
                if (connectionStatus.f() === 'online') {
                    console.log("Fetching DB from the server:");
                    return getDBfileXHR(dbUrl(), serverAttempts)
                            .then(function () { // success
                                console.log('-normal XHR request succeeded.');
                                return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
                            })
                            .catch(function (){
```

Comment: You could use `Observable.of` or `Promise` in angular 2.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have a `.when()` method.

Comment: @PankajParkar but is it really equivalent? Didn't `.when()` wrap non-promise values into promises and leave promises untouched? (so `when(when(1))` is a promise that returns 1) What happens if you do `Observable.of(Observable.of(1))`? You get a stream of streams - edit: Confirmed, it does, therfore they are not equivalent.

Comment: yes you are right @Adam...sorry. I mean I need to replace the use $q in this code, but somewhere else in my app I use $q.when.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the equivalent, with:

```
Promise.resolve(promise).then
```

Which basically makes no distinction between promises and values.

And yes you can instantiate q the same way, but with `new Promise()` rather than `$q()`

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (/* some async task */) {
       resolve('Success!');
    } else {
        reject('Oops... something went wrong');
    }
});
```

and

```
let promise = $q((resolve, reject) => {
    if (/* some async task */) {
       resolve('Success!');
    } else {
       reject('Oops... something went wrong');
    }
});
```

They should be equivalent

Comment: ok thanks, how to instantiate it ? `var deferredVar = new Promise()`?

Comment: Yes, you instantiate the Promise the same way you instantiate `$q`

Comment: so the equivalent of when in your example would be  ̀Promise.resolve(promise).then ` right ?

Comment: Yes. In fact the documentation of [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) shows that `.when` is an alias of `.resolve`. So `$q` has a `.resolve` too that does the same thing.