# $q.when in Angular

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I am migrating from Angular JS to Angular and looking for a `$q.when` equivalent. I have already seen [equivalent of $q.when in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051414/equivalent-of-q-when-in-angular-2) but it's not using Observable. Can we achieve this using Observable? If not, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with `$q.when`? You may just want `Observable.of(...)` as the first comment on that question suggests.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. Observable.of() seems to be the right choice. But if you look below, people have suggested observable.when and Observable.fromEventPattern. This is the confusing part for me. I personally feel that documentation for Observable can be improve.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do, that's why I asked for more information.

Answer (score 2):

$q.when === Observable.fromEventPattern

> Creates an Observable from an API based on addHandler/removeHandler functions.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromEventPattern

Here is an example: Emits clicks happening on the DOM document

```
function addClickHandler(handler) {
  document.addEventListener('click', handler);
}

function removeClickHandler(handler) {
  document.removeEventListener('click', handler);  
}

var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
 addClickHandler,
 removeClickHandler
 ) ;
clicks.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

You can also read my blog 
"$Q map to RxJS" 
https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/q-map-to-rxjs-981936a2b22d

Comment: Thanks! I checked your blog but in your blog you are suggesting to use Observable.of(). Am I missing anything?

Comment: You have just a static value - Observable.of, u if have event handlers - fromEventPattern

Answer (score 1):

I think you could take a look at the RxJS Observable spec which has a 'when' operator: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/when.md